# Enabling emojis in HTML password fields across all platforms

Tags: html, cross-platform, emoji

I am trying to enable the use of emojis in HTML Password fields on a page I am building.  I have a password field defined as:

```
<input type="password" id="txtPassword" />
```

In Android Chrome, I can enter emojis from the keyboard (in this case, Swiftkey keyboard)

In Windows, I can't bring up the Emoji Palette (hotkey: Win + .) when the password field is focused.  The palette does open when a standard text box is focused.   I can also copy and paste emojis from a text box into the password box.

Is there a standard way to configure the password element to ensure all platforms support the operating system and browser default method of entering emojis?

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Make a text input that is transparent and is on top of the password input, and then have what is typed in the text input enter into the password input.

```js
const passwordInput = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
const passwordField = document.getElementById('fieldPassword');

passwordInput.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
     passwordField.value = this.value;
});

function togglePassword() {
  if (passwordField.type === "password") {
    passwordField.type = "text";
  } else {
    passwordField.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```css
#txtPassword {
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" id="txtPassword" />
<input type="password" id="fieldPassword"/>
<button onclick="togglePassword()">Show Password</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So there's no standard way of enabling emoji support cross-platform?  I hate to do a hack like this unless absolutely necessary. :)

Comment: There's no way I can see- this is the best I could come up with. Password inputs are expected to be used for, well, passwords, and most passwords don't have emojis in them, and as such, there's no reason to provide support for it.